# is memcached just instantiating another virtual operating system?

Tags: memcached

I have read a few tutorials on **memcached** and I have a few questions, in order to ease the pain of requests to the default database.

What is being instantiated to allow **memcached** to operate?
Is it virtual operating systems with say mysql installed or is the database in its entirety being stored in ram?

My other question is say i have a blog and using memcache and a user comes to request data from the browser and the request first checks the memcache for the data and sees that the data exists and is displayed to that user.

What if the data being requested doesn't match what is on the original database because i had updated it myself. how will the cache know that i changed it?
Is it always checking to see if the data on the db is the same as what is cached?

Comment: Can you actually understand your own question?

Answer (score 0):

**1**
You will start a memcached server in every machine you need, assigning an amount of memory to dedicate to memcached.
Then with the library memcached you will use the amount of memory on every single server.
NB There is no manner to know  in which server a single object will be stored.

**2**
The mechanism of duplicates is easy: you can set a timeout for the object. When the timeout elapses the system will delete that object.
To store an object you will assign to that object a key as an hash because you don t want that 2 object have the same key.

Comment: Rather than delete, on a timeout, it will flag it as invalid, and **may** be overwritten, but it is not deleted just by expiring.

Answer (score 0):

From [the memcached front-page](http://memcached.org):

> Memcached is an in-memory key-value store for small chunks of arbitrary data (strings, objects) from results of database calls, API calls, or page rendering.

Although memcached is frequently used with MySQL, it has no particular ties to MySQL or any other database. It is just a simple key-value store providing constant time (O(1)) access to data cached by key. The data is stored in memory by the memcached process. (Much of this is explained [on the FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingFAQ)).

Regarding your second question, it is really your application / your responsibility to ensure that memcached is notified of any changes. You can do this via reasonable expiration periods on your cached data or by using a script or the command line interface to manually purge stale entries. Some frameworks will handle notifying memcached of changes provided the change is made through the framework. Ultimately, if you need to ensure that users always have access to the latest data in real-time, than caching is not a good solution for your problem. Caching works on the principle that it's ok to occasionally serve up stale data -- you should construct your application so that it caches data that can be stale, but always uses look-ups to authoritative sources for data that **must** be fresh.